# Jar file hierarchy missing folders like res and src (using jar tf)

Tags: java, jar

I've been working on packaging my res files into my Jar file using eclipse. When I export as a runnable jar or try and use `Runtime.getRuntime().exec();` I get the correct directories, just missing the `res/` or `src/`, etc, which would be a pain to code around. The hierarchy looks something like this:

```
Project
  src
    main
      Main.java
    package_A
      thing1.java
      thing2.java
    package_B
      other_thing1
      other_thing2
    package_C
      …
    package_D
      …
  res
    folder_A
      image_1.png
      image_2.png
      image_3.png
    folder_B
      image_4.png
      image_5.png
    folder_C
      image_6.png
      image_7.png
      image_8.png
      image_9.png
  bin
```

When I run this command as a Runnable Jar File, I get something like this

```
main/Main.java
packageA/thing1.java
packageA/thing2.java
packageB/other_thing1.java
packageB/other_thing2.java
…
folder_A/image_1.png
folder_A/image_2.png
folder_A/image_3.png
folder_B/image_4.png
folder_B/image_5.png
folder_C/image_6.png
folder_C/image_7.png
folder_C/image_8.png
folder_C/image_9.png
```

No `bin`, no `res`, no `src`. Is this just how it is or is it permanent? If not, how do I fix this?

> Edit: Finally fixed it after many many hours. I had to use `getClass().getResource(curPath).toExternalForm()` among many others.

Comment: Typically, folders such as `src` and `res` (or, if using Maven/Gradle, `src/main/java` and `src/main/resources`) are not included in the build output or the JAR file. They are not part of the package structure.

Comment: Is there a way to include them using eclipse?

Comment: Could you explain why you want you? I suspect trying to include them would break your code, assuming you're using the resource-lookup API correctly. For instance, to get one of your images you should be using `SomeClass.class.getResource[AsStream]("/folder_A/image_1.png")`. Notice how that resource name does not include the `res` folder? Also, I assume your `Main.java` file has a `package main;` statement. That means the class file needs to be located at `main/Main.class` relative to the root of the class-path/module. That does not include `src`.

Comment: No, I am going to be adding hundreds more files in the future under different folders in my resource folder, and I have a script that sifts through them and get's their absolute path (That's what I'm using for the getResourceAsStream). This works in Eclipse, but not in a jar file. I've been trying everything I look up for the past two weeks, but using the command line from Java worked. But when I try to find the files, they don't appear unless I insert the "res" or "src" in front.

Comment: That seems wrong. You don't want an "absolute path" for `Class::getResourceAsStream`, unless you mean something like `"/folder_A/image_1.png"` (which is technically an "absolute name" due to the leading `/`, but the root is the root of the class-path/module-path, not of the file system). Perhaps the better solution is for your script to get the paths relative to the `src` / `res` folders. And are you trying to get a list of resources under a package? Because that's not supported by the standard resource API.

Comment: I'm not sure how to choose a subdirectory using tf, as this is my first Java project. Would I do something like `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("jar tf " + jarPath + "/res")`?

Comment: Your problem may be a so-called [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Regardless, I don't understand how this "script" is used, what you're doing with these resource paths, why this all involves `Runtime#exec(String)`, or what your end goal is, and so I don't think I can give a direct and satisfactory answer. But I also don't think adding `src` and `res` to your JAR file is the appropriate solution. Consider designing and creating a [mre] that _demonstrates_ what you're trying to do, and then adding it to your question via an [edit].

Comment: You have misunderstood how application resources work.  Slaw is right;  it is simply not correct for a .jar file to have a `src` or `res` directory in it.  It was never correct.  If you think you need them, you probably have taken the wrong approach to reading resources.